How to Parse msg.Data
Lets say I have a function and I forward the data to another contract
   function Foo(uint256[] myInts, bytes optionalParams) public {
       validator.Validate(msg.data);
   }

I would like to parse the msg.data from my validator. However the msg.data contains the signature so i need to skip the first 4 bytes from the msg.data.
I would like to do something like this:
(
    uint256[] memory values,
    bytes optionalParams
) = abi.decode(encodedParams, (uint256[], bytes));

how do i skip the first 4 bytes of the calldata?

The most direct way would be to slice the resultant bytes in your validator while decoding the encodedParams like encodedParams[4:].
Here's the code snippet for the same:
uint256[] public decodedValues;
bytes public decodeOptionalParams;

function decode(bytes calldata encodedParams) public {
    (decodedValues, decodeOptionalParams) = abi.decode(
        encodedParams[4:],
        (uint256[], bytes)
    );
}

Or, you can pass only the sliced msg.data (like msg.data[4:]) while calling the Validate(), like:
function Foo(uint256[] memory myInts, bytes memory optionalParams) public {
    validator.Validate(msg.data[4:]);
}


Thats the syntax chatgpt gave me but it didnt compile

It's compiling and working fine as expected on my end. Which compiler and EVM version you're using?

I'm using 0.8.12 via-ir.  I'll mark as complete if you said it compiling, I just ended up using a forloop and copying it
